# ionic use video.js throws error

Tags: ionic-framework, video.js, ionic3

I try to use [video.js](https://github.com/videojs/video.js) as my video player, but reaches error:

`Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find module "safe-json-parse/tuple" Error: Cannot find module "safe-json-parse/tuple"`

Steps I did:

1. npm install -S video.js
2. import videojs from 'video.js';
3. write code in palyer.ts => videojs('my-player', { controls: true});
4. above error appears when player page is hit.

Anybody has any idea?  Or what other 3rd party html5 video player can be easily plugged in?

*environment details:*

> ionic info

global packages:

```
@ionic/cli-utils : 1.4.0
Cordova CLI      : 7.0.1 
Ionic CLI        : 3.4.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts              : 1.3.7
@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova       : 1.4.0
@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular : 1.3.1
Cordova Platforms               : android 6.2.3
Ionic Framework                 : ionic-angular 3.3.0
```

System:

```
Node       : v6.10.3
OS         : Linux 4.10
Xcode      : not installed
ios-deploy : not installed
ios-sim    : not installed
npm        : 3.10.10
```

Comment: No errors during `npm install -s video.js`?

Comment: no, should there be?  Instead of using npm, I added its js and css into index.html and `declare var videojs: any` in any ts file. this works but not as elegent as loading npm modules.

Comment: There could have been because the error message said it was unable to find one of video.js dependencies.

Comment: having the same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded the videojs js and css files to assets/ folder and references them in `index.html`.

By this way videojs works, though not as elegant as with npm package

Answer (score 2):

I did the same thing, I had a safe-json-parse module so thought I was fine, but after doing:

npm install -s safe-json-parse

new files were added and the error was gone.

Comment: For me, the css is not loaded. the video player layout is totally disordered. I still need to reference css in index.html.